# How do i remove the LOG-INFO and timestamp in simple-node-logger?

Tags: logging

I'm using the simple-node-logger, and there is a simple thing i want from it which i can't find a way to resolve:

In my server.js, i have the following:

```
 log = require('simple-node-logger').createSimpleLogger('app/logs/log.txt');
```

When i want to write to the file i do this:

```
log.info('blah');
```

Which is working and great, but i want to get rid of the :

```
11:21:21.815 INFO
```

before every log, is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can get the last word ( may be INFO ?) and substring it using Javascript line by line.

Or you can count the maximum word length for timestamp prefix including space and substring it using javascript like below,

```
function formatlogs()
{
    var log=  // log string here
    var lines = log.split('\n'); 
    var len= // length of sample time stamp here like   05:53:26,154 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-/10.251.84.86:8009-12)  is 56
    var newLog;
    for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
        newLog +=  lines[i] .substr(len, lines[i].len)+"\n";
    }
}
```